PdfiumViewer is slow when sending pdf to printer
I am testing PdfiumViewer to send pdf to printer in C#.
References:
https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer
How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?
I found that it's slow when I send pdf containing many pages.
For example, if I send a pdf with 50 pages, it can take 40 seconds to send all the pages to printer queue.
How can the performance be improved?
Thanks for any advice.

Based on my tests, using Adobe Acrobat Reader to send PDFs to the printer is fast. However, there are some problems. For example: 1) I need to set some printer settings, like copies and duplex, in C# code, but it seems this can’t be done by Adobe. 2) Adobe remains open after printing, so I need to figure out when to close it once the printing is done.

Thanks for the suggestion. I will try SumatraPDF.

@K J. I tested SumatraPDF and seems the printing speed is also slow and the spool size is large. I will test other tools.

@K J. Thanks. After trying many possible ways, I may choose a commercial lib instead.
